# How to give a div's padding a different cursor without a wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I am working with a div element that has a pointer cursor on hover. But I want only its padding to have a different cursor.
How can I achieve this without wrapping it in another div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a before pseudo element on the div. Give that dimension =  (size of the div plus whatever padding is required).

Make sure space is reserved for the div plus padding by giving the div margins of the relevant sizes.

That way no special wrapper div is required.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  --padding-top: 10px;
  --padding-right: 20px;
  --padding-bottom: 40px;
  --padding-left: 10px;
  margin: var(--padding-top) var(--padding-right) var(--padding-bottom) var(--padding-left);
  background: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  width: calc(100% + var(--padding-left) + var(--padding-right));
  height: calc(100% + var(--padding-top) + var(--padding-bottom));
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--padding-top));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--padding-left));
  background: pink;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Have just noticed this works OK for top and bottom padding but not left and right - back to the drawing board.

Comment: For my purposes I think this will do thanks

Answer (score 0):

as you can see here on MDN

> Note: Padding creates extra space within an element. In contrast, margin creates extra space around an element.

you can achieve this with `margin` on child and no parent !